# How to block pop ups from appearing on Jmeter WebDriver Sampler

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, popup, selenium-chromedriver

[Pop up picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSssD.png)
I'm trying to set up a performance test in Jmeter using the Webdriver Sampler, and I'm having a lot of trouble with a particular pop up window that chrome throws half of the time. It would save me a lot of time/trouble if someone knows how to disable pop ups in the first place within the Webdriver sampler or maybe through Jmeter or chromedriver config or maybe from setting browser options in the WebDriver sampler. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the nature of this popup it is not possible to come up with the comprehensive solution, I can think only of one option for now:

1. Open `chrome://settings/content/popups` URL in your browser
2. Toggle this switch:

   [image]

The switch is hidden in ShadowDOM so you will have to use `WDS.browser.executeScript()` function in order to get this and convert it to the [WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html)

More information:

- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)
- [A Guide to Working with Shadow DOM using Selenium](https://medium.com/rate-engineering/a-guide-to-working-with-shadow-dom-using-selenium-b124992559f)

Comment: Hi Dimitri, thanks for your help. I have added a picture of the pop up that I am receiving to the original post. I have checked this setting and it is toggled off on my browser and already toggled off on the selenium driver. Any ideas?

Comment: `WDS.browser.executeScript('window.onbeforeunload = null')`